# Question-Answer Game with coin rewards, how to validate answer?

Tags: client-server, validation

I'm making a game that is basically a typical question-answer type. With coins as reward per answered question.

Stacks and requirements:

1. UI frameworks of iOS and Android, no game engine.
2. REST API.
3. No offline feature.

I'm a newbie in making games, and so my questions are:

1. Is it okay if I let the client side validate the answer and let it decide how much coins to add in the database?
2. Or do I make the client side ask for validation of the answer in the server? But I'm thinking this is not ideal because in the game, when you choose an answer, and if the answer is right, the congratulations screen must be instantly popped out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit of both. This comes again and again. Your search terms are client-side prediction and client-side simulation. However, if I point you there, you are going to get something much more complicated than what you need for this simple case...

So, here are the basics:

- The client sends the request to the server
- The client starts playing an animation (if the client can predict what will happen, then it can play the corresponding animation, otherwise, have the client play some busy animation※).
- The client receives the response from the server.
- If the client did a prediction, it compares it with the server response. If they match※※, we are done. Otherwise, the client has to adjust to what happened※※※.

Why do we ask the server? Because cheat prevention. It would be relatively easy to modify the client to tell the server whatever. *Relatively easy compared to hacking the server, assuming state of the art access control.*

Why do we play an animation despite waiting for the server? Because responsiveness. We want the client to react instantly. Do not give the impression that the game didn't register the input, or is otherwise stuck.

Assuming the client knows the right answer, there should be no reason for the prediction to be wrong. Which means this would only affect people trying to cheat. However… If the client knows the right answer, there could be a way to extract it, if there is, well, there you have another way to cheat. Thus, for cheat prevention, you just don't tell the client and let the server decide.

What are you asking the server for anyway? Is it for the right answer? Or for the amount of coins? Let us say we do not care about cheating to get the right answer. We might still not want the client getting more coins than they should. In that case you can say "congratulations", but ask the server for the coins.

Or you do not care about cheating at all.

---

※: For example play the animation of a character opening a chest while waiting for the server response about what is inside.

※※: The server might know things that the client does not. For example it might know that the character you were shooting actually has a shield, and thus the shot won't kill him.

※※※: And then you might see a glitch. These are prevalent on real time games when there is high latency. Another search term for you: lag compensation.

Comment: Wow! This helps, big time! Great answer! Learned some stuff.